# hsqldb no change after backup restore until restart

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb, database-backups

I'm running `hsqldb` in server mode and connecting to it through `Java`. After I try to restore a from a backup via `org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup --extract` the DB files are replaced properly, but the connection seems to only be able to access the pre-backup state of the DB. shutting down and restarting the server + connection does not work; only after terminating the Java process does it seem to update. Any ideas on what the reason might be and how to fix that? I want to display the changes realtime in my GUI without forcing the user to restart the application.

Comment: How did you take a back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not attempt to restore the database from a backup while the server is running.

First SHUTDOWN the database, then restore, follow by restart.

You can run the server with remote_open, which allows you to shutdown the database without shuting down the server. After restoring the backup, you simply connect to the database again.

Comment: Yes, I did try that, still the connection does not get the updated DB contents before the running java process is killed and restarted in some way.

Comment: You probably did not shutdown the database. If you did, a connection to the old database would return an error, but a connection to the new database would return data from the new one.

Comment: You were right, the database wasn't being closed properly. Thanks